# Eigenvalues for $T = T^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The question defines some linear mapping such that $T: V \rightarrow V$ and $T = T^2$ and I am required to give an example of such a mapping other then the identity transformation and prove that if such a $T$ exists, then its eigenvalues are either $0$ or $1$. My example I conjured was the zero transformation function (I think this is a bad example), so it is obvious that:
$$[0_v] = [0_v][0_v]$$
However, I am struggling to prove the eigenvalues for $T$ if $T = T^2$. This is what I started with:
$$TTx = \lambda{}x\\
TTx - \lambda{}x = 0\\
det(TTx - T\lambda{}xT^{-1})$$

And I have a feeling that the idea might be to try to conjure up something with the determinant in that form. However, this has gotten me nowhere and I find the actual eigen analysis is a bit vague. Any hints or advice on how to solve this?

Comment: What did you mean with what you wrote in the line beginning with "However, I am..." ?

Comment: @Joanpemo, I am trying to prove for any general $T = T^2$, the eigenvalues are either $0, 1$

Comment: @Ph That much I understood, yet the line I mentioned above doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Every diagonal matrix with random 0's and 1's on the diagonal will work. Morover, if $v$ is an eigenvalue, then apply it to the equation: $Tv=T^2v \implies \lambda v = \lambda^2 v \implies \lambda = \lambda^2$ and you can solve it!

Comment: Hint: if the matrix is diagonizable, you can compute its square from the diagonal representation.

Comment: what about the matrix $\pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}?$

Comment: @Maffred, thanks!

Comment: Indeed, any projection will do as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's clear the only eigenvalue the zero matrix has is the zero scalar, since for all $\;v\in V\;$:

$$\mathcal O(v)=0=0\cdot v$$

If you also want to prove the only possible eigenvalues of such a matrix are $\;0,1\;$ then suppose $\;\lambda\;$ is an eigenvalue of $\;T=T^2\;$ , then for some **non-zero** $\;v\in V\;$ :

$$\lambda v=Tv=T^2v=T(Tv)=T(\lambda v)=\lambda Tv=\lambda^2 v\implies$$

$$\left(\lambda-\lambda^2\right)v=0\implies \lambda=\lambda^2\iff \lambda= 0\;\;or\;\;1$$

Comment: I think some people really rush a lot to downvote when they read something  they don't understand. If at least they'd explain their downvote....

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I think the reason why is from your initial answer may have been vague from the question, that said I have upvoted it since

Comment: @PhilipTsang What's vague? You said you thought of the zero matrix as obvious example yet you're struggling with its eigenvalues . I don't care about the downvotes, as clearly one doesn't get money for points, yet it is really disappointing having people downvoting without being a little educated and writing down the reason for it. We all could learn from that.

Comment: I was struggling with proving that the eigenvalues for any $T = T^2$ were either $0$ or $1$, not the eigenvalues for the zero matrix. Sorry for any misunderstanding

Comment: @PhilipTsang It's fine. If you explain I can, hopefully, understand.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Then
$$\begin{align*}
Tx &= \lambda x
\\
T(Tx) &= T(\lambda x)
\\
T^2 x &= \lambda Tx
\\
T^2 x &= \lambda^2 x
\\
T x &= \lambda^2 x
\end{align*}$$

Thus, $\lambda^2 = \lambda$, so $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda = 1$.